# why the size of string is same as number of char but length is one more than number of char?

Tags: c

I used the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
  char c[] = {'J', 'O', 'H', 'N'};
  printf("size (bytes)=%d\n", sizeof(c));
  int len = strlen(c);
  printf("Length = %d\n", strlen(c));
  printf("%s", c);
```

The output size of the string is 4, but the length is 5. is the string not supposed to have `/0` at the end? So the output size of the string should be 5, but the length is 4.
If I write code as char `c[] = {'J', 'O', 'H', 'N', \0};` or `c[] = "JOHN"` then I got output size of the string is 5, the length is 4

Comment: `strlen()` looks for the trailing 0 byte. `c` doesn't have a trailing 0, so it reads whatever happens to be in memory after it, looking for the next 0. By accident there was just 1 byte before a 0, so the length is 5. It could be anything.

Comment: Calling `strlen()` when the string doesn't have a `0` terminator causes undefined behavior.

Comment: This is why you should write `char c[] = "JOHN";`. When you use a string literal, it automatically adds the 0 terminator.

Comment: A string literal like `"JOHN"` will have the null-terminator added by the compiler. A character array that you initialize character by character (like in the shown code) will not have any null-terminator.

Comment: Every C function that begins `str...` and every argument expecting a string (e.g. `puts (string);` expects a *nul-terminated* string. That is the definition of a C-string. A sequence of characters ending with `'\0'` (plain old ASCII `0`). That how all string functions know where the string ends. That's also how you loop over each char in `char *str = "abcdef";` with `for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) { ... }`

Comment: So your question is flawed from the start.  You asked, "why the size of string is...", but you do *not have a string!*  So all bets are off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, a *string* is a sequence of character values including a 0-valued terminator - the string `"JOHN"` would be represented as the sequence `{'J', 'O', 'H', 'N', 0 }`.

Strings are stored in arrays of character type - because the you need to store the terminator in addition to the characters of the string, the size of the array has to be *at least* one more than the length of the string.  IOW, to store the 4-character string `"JOHN"` you need an array that's *at least* 5 elements wide.

Had you initialized the array as

```
char c[] = "JOHN";
```

then the terminator would have properly been accounted for.

If the terminator isn't present, then what you have isn't a string and the various `str*` library functions won't handle it properly.  In your case above, `strlen` looked through the elements `{'J', 'O', 'H', 'N'}` and didn't find the 0 terminator, so it *kept looking past the end of the array* until it saw a zero-valued byte.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a string in C is that it is an array of characters, terminated by a null character, or `'\0'`.

You wrote:

```
char c[] = {'J', 'O', 'H', 'N'};
```

So let's see.

- array of char: ✅
- terminated by a null character: ❌

So `c` is *not* a string.  So it's not valid to call `strlen` on it, and it's not valid to print it out using `printf`'s `%s` format.

You could make it a proper string by changing the initialization to:

```
char c[] = {'J', 'O', 'H', 'N', 0};
```

or equivalently

```
char c[] = {'J', 'O', 'H', 'N', '\0'};
```

Or it would be easier and clearer to just write

```
char c[] = "JOHN";
```

When you use a string literal (that is, a string in double quotes) as an initializer for a character array like that, the compiler automatically does exactly the same thing for you as if you had written `{'J', 'O', 'H', 'N', '\0'};`, but it's obviously a lot less typing.